# DB Sharding: Data migration to another machine

Tags: database, database-migration, sharding, data-migration

I have a some data that is sharded and kept in `DB1`, `DB2` and `DB3` hosted on `Machine1`. Now, to scale the system, I need to move shard `DB1` from `Machine1` to `Machine2`. Once the move is complete, all requests to shard `DB1` will be routed to `Machine2`.

Assume that we have reads, writes and updates coming to `DB1` all the time. How can I do the migration without any downtime to read/write/update?

We can make `DB1` readonly during the migration window and copy the data to `Machine2`. Once copy is complete, we can route traffic to `Machine2` and allow writes.

But what if we want to do the same while writes are also happening?

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found couple of ways to do this.

**Solution 1**

For the purpose of copying the shard to another physical machine, break that into several small segments. Trigger a script to copy segment by segment from M1 to M2. While the copy is happening, replicate incoming writes to both M1 and M2.

1. All newly written rows will be written to new copy as well
2. Any updates to existing segments which are not yet copied will be taken care when that segment is copied to M2 in the future
3. Updates to already copied segments will be applied to M2 as well because M2 also has that segment
4. Writes to a particular segment is blocked while the segment is being copied. Once the copy is complete, write is completed and it's same as #3 above.
5. Once all the segments are copied successfully, stop writes to M1. At this point, DB1 in M1 is stale and can be deleted safely.

**Solution 2**

As before, break the shard into several smaller segments.

1. Schedule a script to segment by segment to M2
2. Any updates to existing segments which are not yet copied will be taken care when that segment is copied to M2 in the future
3. When there is an update to a segment that's already copied, mark that segment as dirty to be copied again.
4. Newly created segments are by default marked as dirty
5. Once copy is complete, start another pass to copy all the dirty blocks again
6. Repeat the passes until the number of dirty blocks is below a certain threshold. At that point, queue incoming writes (increases write latency), copy the remaining dirty blocks, commit the queued writes to new machine, change the configuration to write to M2 and start accepting writes.

I feel *Solution 2* is better because it doesn't write to two places and hence client write requests will be faster.